# aspxcombobox populating on the fly

Tags: asp.net, javascript, firefox, combobox, devexpress

Aspxcombobox populating on the fly works fine with IE, but with others browsers, when using arrow keys for navigation, the second depended control, always has value for the first next and not for the current, so I have a bit of delay ...

Comment: I'm guessing you mean Cascading DropDowns in ASP.NET WebForms? Could you post some code?

Comment: please read the answer, because there was no enough characters left ...

Answer (score 1):

To David,

Yeah it's similar to cascading DropDowns in Asp.NET webforms.
Some code using callback event on the second combobox (even other control is not problem-should be similar issue):

```
protected void cmbCity_Callback(object source, DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
    {
    int CountryID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbCountry.SelectedIndex.ToString());

    taLocationOPP.FillByCountry(dsOPP_Tracking.tblLocation, CountryID);
    cmbCity.DataSource = dsOPP_Tracking.Tables["tblLocation"];
    cmbCity.ValueField = "iLocationId";
    cmbCity.TextField = "strLocation";
    cmbCity.DataBind();
    cmbCity.SelectedIndex = 0;


}
```

**P.S.**

> cmbCountry is parent combobox...

normally I get required result, but with some delay in firefox for example..etc etc...as it's described in the posted question...

Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: If you need to add clarification to your question, you should generally edit your question. It is also good practice when doing so to indicate where you edited it (by putting **UPDATE** before your update for example).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ASPxComboBox/ClientAPI.aspx

Comment: already I'm using a lot of demos code from devExpress tutorials, and I'm familiar with this example, but the issue is how much time it takes when you select for example Germany (more cities inside the depended combobox, and then you're selecting immediately other country, and the second combobox is still binding from the previous country)...anyway thanks for your efforts :)